# MX Master 3 - Command + Tab Shortcup in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, logitech, mxmaster3

I have a MX Master 3 Mouse, I am using a Macbook Pro 2018 running OSX 10.14.6. I use the Logitech Options software to program the thumb button to do a `Command + Tab` to change windows, a quick tap switches to the previous window, a press and hold + scroll cycles through all open windows. But when I am using VS Code it pastes the contents of my clipboard and THEN does the desired window change. Does anybody have any idea what is going on and why it is pasting. I have checked my VS Code key bindings and there is nothing bound to `Command + Tab` and paste is the normal `Command + V`. I have disabled the mapping on the button within the Logitch Options software and it works as expected (the button does nothing, including no paste).

Comment: My temporary solution was to disable that button only when using VS code (which is done through Logitech Options), this is not a great solution.

Comment: I have the same issues, somehow all buttons will paste clipboard and THEN perform the action. are you able to find a solution ?